# How can I associate the First Person Controller in Unity with the VROneSDK and VROneSDKHead?

Tags: c#, vrone

I would like to combine the First Person Controller from the Unity standard assets with the camera from the VROneSDK and VROneSDKHead, where the rotation of the character is controlled by the head tracking from the VROneSDK.

How can I do this with the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's FPS controller uses the script MouseLook.cs to control the camera. The script is attached twice in this perfab. At the root object the script controls horizontal rotation and at the camera the script controls the vertical rotation.

Remove both scripts from the FPS controller.

Disable the main camera in the FPS controller. Attach the VROneSDK prefab to the FPS controller (as child of FPS controller) and copy the position and rotation values from the previous camera.

Create a new C# script VROneHeadLook.cs with the following content:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class VROneHeadLook : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool useAngleX = true;   
    public bool useAngleY = true;
    public bool useAngleZ = true;
    public bool useRealHorizontalAngle = false;
    public bool resetViewOnTouch = true;

    private Quaternion initialRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    private Quaternion currentRotation;
    private static Vector3 gyroAngles; // original angles from gyro
    private static Vector3 usedAngles; // converted into unity world coordinates

    private int userSleepTimeOut; // original device SleepTimeOut setting
    private bool gyroAvail = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Input.compensateSensors = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (gyroAvail == false) {
            if (Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles != Vector3.zero && Time.frameCount > 30) {
                gyroAvail = true;
                initialRotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
            }
            return; // early out
        }

        // reset origin on touch or not yet set origin
        if(resetViewOnTouch && (Input.touchCount > 0))
            initialRotation = Input.gyro.attitude;

        // new rotation
        currentRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(initialRotation)*Input.gyro.attitude;

        gyroAngles = currentRotation.eulerAngles;

        //usedAngles = Quaternion.Inverse (currentRotation).eulerAngles;
        usedAngles = gyroAngles;

        // reset single angle values
        if (useAngleX == false)
            usedAngles.x = 0f;
        if (useAngleY == false)
            usedAngles.y = 0f;
        if (useAngleZ == false)
            usedAngles.z = 0f;

        if (useRealHorizontalAngle)
            usedAngles.y *= -1;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(-usedAngles.x, usedAngles.y, usedAngles.z));
    }
    void OnEnable() {
        // sensor on
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        initialRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        gyroAvail = false;

        // store device sleep timeout setting
        userSleepTimeOut = Screen.sleepTimeout;
        // disable sleep timeout when app is running
        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        // restore original sleep timeout
        Screen.sleepTimeout = userSleepTimeOut;
        //sensor off
        Input.gyro.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Attach this script to the FPS controller and the VROneSDK prefab. For the FPS controller set all script variables to false except 'Use Angle Y' which should be true.

For the script attached to the VROneSDK prefab set all script variables to false except 'Use Angle X'

Comment: Thank you, Harry. I also set "Use Real Horizontal Angle" to true on both the FPS controller and the VROneSDK prefab. However, the script does not set the camera to the correct initial device rotation. It always looks forward to 0,0,0 which causes the gyro rotations to be off when the app is started with the device placed flat on the table. How can I get the camera to rotate to the initial device rotation at startup?